# SELECT and list children and parent

Tags: php, mysql, sql, select

I need a SQL query for the following COMPLEX task...

I need to to select from a column named `parent_id`. If a row has 0 for `parent_id` it means that it's a category (it also has the `type` column which says `cat` for category), if a row has 1 or more for `parent_id` it means that it is a rule. The `parent_id` of a rule, is the `rule_id` of a category.

The table structure with some data in it:
[image: phpMyAdmin table data]

I need to select in a way, that EACH category, has its children under it. From the picture we would get this:

```
Sample Category 1
   Sample rule 1
Sample Category 2
```

I tried some some queries that I found from here, but none worked.

This is what I tried last:

```
'SELECT *
FROM ' . RULES_TABLE . ' AS parent
    LEFT JOIN ' . RULES_TABLE . ' AS child 
    ON child.parent_id = parent.rule_id 
WHERE parent.parent_id = 0
     AND parent.public = 1
ORDER BY parent.cat_position, child.rule_position';
```

It returned *Sample rule 1* only.

Ideas?

Comment: You can't do that in sql with a single query if that's what you're asking... please be more specific, you can do it with a query for categories and subqueries for rules or even in a single query if you are ok with sacrificing categories with no rules from the results and receiving the category name for each rule, or without sacrificing empty categories with concatenated (with commas or some character of your choice) rule names

Comment: I could solve this by putting a query inside a loop created by another query, but that's not recommend and I shouldn't be doing that. This is why I asked here, for an acceptable solution that doesn't include queries in loops.

Comment: If you have a solution that doesn't include queries in loops, please post it.

Comment: @xception can you show me an example that does the same thing as below but with subqueries?

Comment: group_concat_max_size not enough? there is another way with a single query but requires a bit more processing on the programming side, or I could do it with subqueries as well!

Comment: Well, whichever is the best, you decide, or even better if you have time show me both :D

Comment: @xception I am sorry to interrupt your work again, but I don't use PDO and I can't really seem to make use of your edit below. I would really appreciate if you show me the subquery version. Again, sorry for being such a mess and asking so much, I promise this is the last time I am asking for a complete new query.

Comment: you don't have to use PDO to use that, I just wrote the sample with PDO in mind, you can use it regardless of database interface you use from php, the whole idea is that this way you don't get them grouped so you have to group them yourself instead, you get them in order though but instead of getting 1 row for each c.rule_id you get one for each r.rule_title, so you have to check when c.rule_id is different from the previous row's c.rule_id and only if it's different output c.rule_title, if it's the same you get the different r.rule_title values for current c.rule_id, hope it's clear now

Comment: If you still can't figure it out open a new question please because this already extended a lot, include the current query you are using and the php code you use to output data and let me know about it so I can answer you. Ask how you can get rid of group_concat in the most efficient way.

Comment: @xception There you go: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12846021/select-and-list-children-and-parent-alternative

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this fiddle http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/0a9c5/16, sql code below

```
SELECT c.rule_id, c.rule_title, GROUP_CONCAT(r.rule_title)
FROM RULES_TABLE AS c
LEFT JOIN RULES_TABLE AS r
    ON r.parent_id = c.rule_id
WHERE c.parent_id IS NULL AND c.public = 1
GROUP BY c.rule_id
ORDER BY c.cat_position, c.rule_position;
```

left out php-ization of code on purpose to maintain syntax highlighting, which seems not to work anyway

If you exceed maximum allowed group_concat size you can either increase it or use the following version, and do a bit more processing in php:

```
SELECT c.rule_id, c.rule_title, r.rule_title as r_rule_title
FROM RULES_TABLE AS c
LEFT JOIN RULES_TABLE AS r
    ON r.parent_id = c.rule_id
WHERE c.parent_id IS NULL AND c.public = 1
ORDER BY c.cat_position, c.rule_position;
```

and in php, skeleton code provided only, fill in with the actual values, assuming you use pdo and your pdostatement var is named `$query`:

```
$old_rule_id = null;
$rrt = array(); // will contain all r.rule_titles for a give c.rule_id
while( ($i = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ)) !== false ) {
    if( $old_rule_id != $i->rule_id ) {
        if( count($rrt) ) {
            echo ... all the data for previous rule from $rrt ...
            echo ... end of previous element ...
            $rrt = array(); // empty it to collect new data
        }
        echo ... start of current element use data from $i->rule_id and $i->rule_title ...
        $old_rule_id = $rule_id;
    }
    $rrt[] = $i->r_rule_title;
}
// the following is the same if from inside the while, minus reinitialization of $rrt;
if( count($rrt) ) {
    echo ... all the data for previous rule from $rrt ...
    echo ... end of previous element ...
}
```

replace stuff between ... with valid code

Comment: `You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'GROUP BY c.rule_id' at line 7 [1064]`

Comment: @Dugi updated with fiddle, group by must be before order by, anyway it works now, only thing is you get rule names in a single string separated by commas

Comment: Well yeah, it does work perfectly. Will be accepting your answer shortly. Thanks a lot :)

Comment: There is a bad thing happening. The query is splitting a complete string into comma separated string. EG: A sample row from rule_description says `I will be going there`, the query makes it `I, will, be, going, there`.

Comment: How about you give me some actual data so I can figure out what you're trying to do, alternatively use `GROUP_CONCAT(r.rule_title SEPARATOR ' ')` instead to use spaces instead of commas, or if you already have the spaces use `GROUP_CONCAT(r.rule_title SEPARATOR '')`

Comment: Sorry. That's not the problem here. I need to use commas too when creating a rule sometimes, and I am using explode inside a loop to make the query result an array, and then loop it again to get results of my need.

Comment: Updated fiddle http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/aa0e1/2 , just in case. Post some real data / code, I can't guess what's happening

Comment: you can use whatever you want as separator, you can even make it multiple character as `SEPARATOR '--I'M_A_HUGE_SEPARATOR_REMOVE_ME--'`

Comment: Lol, no need to be offensive. Thanks, that fixed the problem.

Comment: Didn't mean to be offensive, just showing you you can use very long separators if you wanted to, edited, hope it's better now, well forgot the \ before '

Comment: Is there any word limit in this query? It some point it stops fetching data for a certain category. It breaks the world like: **Hello I am Dugi and I wor**

Comment: The result is truncated to the maximum length that is given by the group_concat_max_len system variable -- you can change it with `SET group_concat_max_len = new_length;` -- for more information see http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat

Comment: @Dugi I'm sorry but you made me really curious about this, why would you save each word in a separate entry in the table? Doesn't make much sense to me.

Comment: That's how the administration stores stuff in the db :D

Answer (score -1):

Using FOR XML EXPLICIT you can get a hierarchical list.

Try this:

```
SELECT 
 1 Tag,
 null Parent,
 '' [root!1!name],
 null [category!2!id],
 null [category!2!name],
 null [rule!3!id],
 null [rule!3!name]

UNION ALL 

SELECT DISTINCT 
 2 Tag,
 1 Parent,
 null,
 rule_id [category!2!id],
 rule_title [category!2!name],
 null [rule!3!id],
 null [rule!3!name]
FROM rules
WHERE parent_id = 0 and rule_type = 'cat'

UNION ALL 

SELECT  
 3 Tag,
 2 Parent,
 null,
 parent_id [category!2!id],
 null [category!2!name],
 rule_id [rule!3!id],
 rule_title [rule!3!name]
FROM rules
WHERE parent_id > 0 and rule_type = 'rule'

FOR XML EXPLICIT
```

For more information visit http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189068.aspx

Comment: Uhm, the question is about mysql not mssql